# Eclipse Helios settings are gone everytime I restart it

Tags: eclipse, settings, maven-plugin

Everytime I restart my eclipse helios I see it having lost all its views, perspective and all its setting. And as I have a maven eclipse installed on it, it starts updating nexus-maven-repository-index central which seem to a decade to do its thing.

I was very happy with Galilio but I needed to work on a project that asked me to use helios or above. And I've been feeling burnt ever since I switched to Galileo.

Does eclipse helios has any incompatibilities with any of Java 6 versions. I am using jdk1.6.0_32.

Could someone please help me with these problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Worst case, once you have resetup all the preference, view & perspective, do the following

Export > general > Preferences > somename.epf

next time when you open eclipse and if the preference is wiped out, then you can 
Import > general >preference>somename.epf.

It doesn't fix your problem, but will get you up running...

Comment: I removed the earlier one and just installed a new eclipse helios and all the plugins and now it seem to work just fine. Thanks for the temporary solution for the worst case though :).